# How to add an object to multiprocessing processes?

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, ipython, pool, multiprocess

I'm used to using an `ipcluster` from `ipyparallel`, where I can upload an object to workers via `dview['object'] = object`.

I'm wondering how to do this with `multiprocessing`. I'd like it to be asynchronous so I can eventually tabulate the jobs that have finished to show a progress bar, but for now I'm mainly interested in uploaded an object (e.g. a big mem dataframe) so that I don't have to pass it with the function and thus slow things down :

```
from ipyparallel import Client
import pandas as pd

rc = Client(profile='default')
dview = rc[:]
lview = rc.load_balanced_view()

myobject = pd.read_table('/some/path/')
#                                  ############################################
dview['myobject'] = myobject       #### <- how do I do this using multiprocess?
#                                  ############################################

def dowork(rowstart):
    rowend = rowstart + (1000-1)
    ...
    return pd.DataFrame(work)

jobs = []
for i in range(0,len(myobject.index),1000):
    jobs.append(lview.apply_async(dowork, i))

newdf = pd.concat([j.r for j in jobs])
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *how to do this with `multiprocessing`?*

By definition, the process-based parallelism in python copies the whole state of the python interpreter, including all its internal variables et cetera to the new worker-processes upon their instantiation. The operating system decides, how that could or could not be done ( read the `multiprocessing` documentation for all details, risks and other drawbacks ).

While this is an expensive, yet principally needed step so as to escape from the central GIL-lock monopolistic re-**`[SERIAL]`**-isation of all python processing, this method assures your processes to "know" **`myobject`** by-design ( the `icluster` had to re-broadcast the object to all remote nodes and, because of the several orders of magnitude higher costs ( going from a few hundreds `[ns]` to pretty well above `[ms]` ) of local/remote `SER/DES`-operations + L2/L3-network-level transport services' latencies, it let that care on you, not to forget to distribute all those objects your code will need, manually before jobs were going to get launched.

Colocated `multiprocessing`-spawned processes "know" the same as the parent python interpreter, so your life gets easier in this context.